# Azure Portal start screen

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm using quite a few resources in Azure and my start screen is filled with tiles belonging to multiple projects. Is there a way to group tiles together so I can collapse and expand them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resource Group is the primary feature to bundle resources in logical buckets. But there is another cool feature in the portal I use a lot. Notice the '+ New Dashboard' button above the tiles. With this you can add multiple dekstop like dashboards and switch between various tiles setups.

Comment: You can also use tags to group random sets of resources together.